# Replace a value of an object by ID in React JS

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have an array of objects like so:

```
Array [
  Object {
    "id": 1,
    "question": "Have you had any of the following symptoms in the last 24 hours?",
    "choices": Array [
      Object {
        "answer": false,
        "choice": "Cough",
        "id": 1,
        "questionID": 1,
      },
      Object {
        "answer": false,
        "choice": "Shortness of Breath",
        "id": 2,
        "questionID": 1,
      },
      Object {
        "answer": false,
        "choice": "Cold",
        "id": 3,
        "questionID": 1,
      },
    ],
  },
  Object {
    "id": 2,
    "question": "Have you had at least TWO of the following symptoms in the last 24 hours?",
    "choices": Array [
      Object {
        "answer": false,
        "choice": "Fever (usually 37.6 C or greater)",
        "id": 4,
        "questionID": 2,
      },
      Object {
        "answer": false,
        "choice": "Chills",
        "id": 5,
        "questionID": 2,
      },
      Object {
        "answer": false,
        "choice": "Repeated shaking with chills",
        "id": 6,
        "questionID": 2,
      },
      Object {
        "answer": false,
        "choice": "Muscle Pain",
        "id": 7,
        "questionID": 2,
      },
      Object {
        "answer": false,
        "choice": "Headache",
        "id": 8,
        "questionID": 2,
      },
      Object {
        "answer": false,
        "choice": "Sore Throat",
        "id": 9,
        "questionID": 2,
      },
      Object {
        "answer": false,
        "choice": "Diarrhea",
        "id": 10,
        "questionID": 2,
      },
      Object {
        "answer": false,
        "choice": "New loss of taste or smell",
        "id": 11,
        "questionID": 2,
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

Which I use as dynamic data to generate a questionnaire on Android:

[image]

The object is in a `state` therefore what I'd like to do is change an `answer` key to false or true depending on what its sibling `id` is.

E.g.:

```
Object {
     "answer": false,
     "choice": "Cold",
     "id": 3,
     "questionID": 1,
}
```

When I click on a `choice` with an `id` of 3, the `answer` should be updated to true.

I am trying to point to the index of `question` and the id of `choices` but it returns undefined

```
<View>
  {questions.map((question, questionIndex) => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>{question.question}</Text>

        {question.choices.map((choice) => {
          return (
            <View style={styles.checkboxContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.choice}>{choice.choice}</Text>
              <CheckBox
                style={styles.checkbox}
                value={choice.answer}
                onValueChange={() =>
                  handleChange(questionIndex, choice.id)
                }
              />
            </View>
          );
        })}
      </View>
    );
  })}
  <TextInput style={styles.remark} multiline={true} />
  <View style={{ marginTop: 20 }}></View>
  <Button title="Confirm Decline" color="red" />
</View>
```

This is the handleChange function:

```
const handleChange = ( questionIndex, id ) => {
  console.log("Question Index: " + questionIndex);
  //Question Index: undefined
  console.log("Choice ID: " + id);
  //Choice ID: undefined
};
```

Comment: you don't need to destructure the arguments `const handleChange = ({ questionIndex, id }) => {` should be `const handleChange = ( questionIndex, id ) => {` because  you aren't passing an object to `handleChange`

Comment: @pilchard thank you, I have edited it and now the index and choice ID are fine but I'm still having trouble on change the object values

Comment: is this a functional component? Are you using `useState()`?

Comment: @pilchard yes, there is a ```question``` and ```setQuestion``` state that stores the JSON data

Comment: Please see my answer, `setState` is handled at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the relevant answer with the following.

```
questionState[questionIndex].choices.find(c => c.id == id).answer
```

and toggle it from `true` to `false` or vice versa like so

```
const choice = questionState[questionIndex].choices.find(c => c.id == id);
choice.answer = !choice.answer;
```

But it is more robust to explicitly retrieve the value from the checkbox and set the answer accordingly.

For this you will need to pass the `event` to `handleChange` so that you can access the value of the changed element.

```
<CheckBox style={styles.checkbox} value={choice.answer} 
  onValueChange={(event) =>
    handleChange(event, questionIndex, choice.id)
  }
/>
```

and setting it becomes

```
questionState[questionIndex].choices.find(c => c.id == id).answer = event.target.checked;
```

---

**Updating state**

When updating nested state objects you need to be particularly careful not to mutate the state.

Assuming you are using the `useState()` hook you can avoid this by passing a callback to `setState`.

```
const handleChange = ( event, questionIndex, id ) => {

  setQuestionState(prevState => {
    prevState[questionIndex].choices.find(c => c.id == id).answer = event.target.checked;
  })

};
```

If not, you will need to manually ensure that you are cloning each level of the state object before finally setting the state with the updated values/objects.